# How to deal with the inundation of low quality questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, low-quality-posts

**Preface**

This post has received a lot of negative attention in a relatively short period of time, but I just want to clarify that this question is about how can we effectively deal with the growing pains of such a successful site/community.

It is not meant to harbor an ill-will towards anyone but rather as a discussion point for maintaining longevity.

I personally have less and less ambition to visit this site as a contributor with each passing day.

---

Stack Overflow has become a successful central hub for asking and answering programming questions; zero doubt about this.

The issue comes into play when newcomers fail to abide by the quality guidelines set forth in this community. I feel that far too may users simply see this site as a [**black box**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_box) for dumping their issue and waiting for a response.

This is made most evident in questions where users post only part of the issue and keep tacking on shallow reasons why a given solution does not work for them until they have a plethora of semi-valid answers. What's worse is when they decline to provide additional necessary information when requested and claim that everything is in the question already. If it was in the question *then I wouldn't be asking*.

I think that overall this chips away at the morale of able-minded users and definitely creates a sense of us versus them. The crummy part is that "them" is increasing exponentially faster than "us".

Below are some ideas I've been contemplating with for a while. It is not a suggestion to implement both but rather pick one, the other, or both if you really like it.

---

**Implement minimum rep filtration**

I can already set tag filters such as PHP, jQuery, etc...

I would love to see an option to enhance this filter to something like `PHP tag + OP rep >= 4000`

I think this could be enabled for users at like 5K rep **OR** we can allow it for all users, but the upper-bound is equal to the user's current rep.

So my current max would be `PHP tag + OP rep >= 10496`

A newbie could do `PHP tag + OP rep >= 1` until they get more rep.

This feature is aimed at veteran user comfort. Kindly, keep low quality questions out of my face, pretty please.

Yes, I am aware that pure Stack Overflow newbies could be 20-year professionals in the respective tag and ask an incredibly good question, but missing that question is a risk that I am willing to voluntarily take since the odds are about 1:20000.

---

**Enforce a wait time for newbies and people with a poor question asking track record**

Allow these users to ask questions but place these questions in a queue. After 1 or 2 (preferably) hours release the question to Stack Overflow as if it is a freshly asked question. I suggest maxing users to two questions at a time in the queue, but I am open to all recommendations.

I think this is a good way to give new users the hint that there are quality guidelines at play here and they should use this wait time to actually do a better job of googling or reviewing the automated dupe suggestions.

During this time they should be allowed to remove their question from the queue.

I think moderators should be allowed to manually enforce a user to use a queue. Kind of like the week-long question ban but more of a week-long "must use the queue ban".

---

On a side note:

Sometimes I feel as though users must have installed an IDE plug-in which automatically posts syntax and compilation errors directly to Stack Overflow, but my theory has yet to be substantiated.

Comment: "Sometimes I feel as though users must have installed an IDE plug-in which automatically posts syntax and compilation errors directly to SO..." It's an Eclipse plug-in that posts screen shots.

Comment: Allowing our productive members the ability to ignore new users will only ensure that low quality posts will never be cleaned up and users will be unable to ever gain reputation unless they already have reputation.

Comment: Question ghettos have been proposed many times before.

Comment: @Clay07g Users can get reputation by answering. Nobody is proposing to filter out the _answers_ by new users.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am not proposing a ghetto, I just want to maintain my sanity. I would be interested to read some of those "ghetto" posts if you have the links.

Comment: @bro If you filter out questions based on rep, you automatically filter out the answers to those questions. Which means you've essentially split up the website, where you and I can't interact with each other, because you don't see my questions, and your questions are too advanced for me to answer. Since new users rarely upvote, people answering new-user questions wouldn't gain the rep needed to get into your elitist society. Eventually, you and you're reputation-generation will die and the billions of uncleaned crap that you filtered out of your life will remain.

Comment: @Clay07g I think that forcing productive members to be inundated with low quality posts is the greater evil. The low quality posts aren't decreasing, they are increasing. Let the low quality users duke it out; they can vote too you know...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus They can, but they don't.

Comment: @Clay07g Great. New garbage collection rule: `every 6 hours, delete questions which have a score of zero or less, 20 views or less, and have no answers.`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus You've just ensured that I can not answer questions from people on opposite timezones. Unless you propose I never sleep. However, I think a garbage collector isn't a bad idea necessarily. 6 hours is absolutely absurd, though.

Comment: @Clay07g I am active in review queues, so I'm not shying away from cleaning up. It's just that when I look for questions _to answer_, I need a distilled list for it to be worth my time. It's all volunteer effort; each volunteer should get to decide how to focus it.

Comment: @Clay07g It wasn't a fully serious suggestion. SO already has some garbage collection going on but I forget what the conditions are...

Comment: @bro I'm not saying you're personally doing something wrong. But if StackOverflow implements it, it gives permission for users to place lower importance on new members. That precedent essentially tells new users they are simply less important unless they are experts in answering technical questions. I can't see how that aligns with SO's goals.

Comment: @Clay07g April Wensel doesn't sound an advocate of elitism (have you seen her posts about SO?) but her advice to high-rep SO users is similar: "You can also set clear boundaries. Maybe you only answer questions one day a week, or you don’t answer questions from new users. Setting boundaries is an essential component of self-care". (From [Suffering on Stack Overflow](https://medium.com/@Aprilw/suffering-on-stack-overflow-c46414a34a52))

Comment: downvoters, explain yourselves

Answer (score 3):

It's unfortunate that you put two proposals together; I like the first but not the second. I like the first one so much that I wrote a simple [userscript for reputation-based filtering](https://stackapps.com/questions/7496/reputation-based-filter-for-search-results) which is the main thing that prevents me from closing the browser tab soon after looking at new questions.  (My reputation cut-off for this site is mere 10 points; I only hide the questions from users with < 10 rep.)

It's also in line with [Tim Post's plans from way back in 2016](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285889):

> We're going to explore some ideas for better filtering of the questions that you see indicated by information that you give us. If you really only enjoy solving medium to difficult problems, that's what we need to prioritize showing you. We're going to have some discussions on ways this can be accomplished when we come to it.

I guess we are still waiting for the outcome of said discussions... One of early drafts of new navigation had a reputation filter; unfortunately it disappeared in a later iteration, and then the new nav went away at all.

I am not really concerned that "new users will get no attention". There are plenty of users (including high reputation users) who *love* tracking down missing semicolons and close parentheses. They are never going to use such filters. And of course, other relatively new users are unlikely to limit their search results by reputation, as they seek to build their own by answering.

Comment: Thinking about it, your Xmonkey script might be even more useful for new accounts with sub-prime experience and trainiing.  Instead of filtering out <10 Q&A, it could easily filter in Q <100, and so present a range of Q&A that are more likely to suited to their level of knowedge.  They could up the limit or turn off the script as time goes on:)